# printing a string in object oriented programming

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a MOOC on Python Programming and am having a hard time finding a solution to a problem set. I hope you can provide some assistance.

The problem statement is:
This problem uses the same Pet, Owner, and Name classes from the previous problem.

In this one, instead of printing a string that lists a single pet's owner, you will print a string that lists all of a single owner's pets.

Write a function called get_pets_string. get_pets_string should have one parameter, an instance of Owner. get_pets_string should return a list of that owner's pets according to the following format:

David Joyner's pets are: Boggle Joyner, Artemis Joyner

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        
class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []
```

Add your get_pets_string function here!

Here's my code:

```
def get_pets_string(Owner):
    result = Owner.name.first + " " + Owner.name.last + "'s" + " " + "pets are:"  + Pet.name
    return result
```

My code is getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Pet' has no attribute 'name'
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

Below are some lines of code that will test your function. You can change the value of the variable(s) to test your function with different inputs.

If your function works correctly, this will originally
print:
David Joyner's pets are: Boggle Joyner, Artemis Joyner
Audrey Hepburn's pets are: Pippin Hepburn

```
owner_1 = Owner(Name("David", "Joyner"))
owner_2 = Owner(Name("Audrey", "Hepburn"))

pet_1 = Pet(Name("Boggle", "Joyner"), owner_1)
pet_2 = Pet(Name("Artemis", "Joyner"), owner_1)
pet_3 = Pet(Name("Pippin", "Hepburn"), owner_2)

owner_1.pets.append(pet_1)
owner_1.pets.append(pet_2)
owner_2.pets.append(pet_3)

print(get_pets_string(owner_1))
print(get_pets_string(owner_2))
```

Could you please offer some guidance on what I'm not doing right with my code?

Comment: In statement `Pet.name`, the `name` is assumed as class variable. You want to access the `name` attribute of a `Pet` object not `Pet` class

Comment: `Pet` in `Pet.name` is referring to class. You want to refer to `Owner.pets` list of pets instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `name` is an instance variable of `Pet` class. So, to access `name` of `Pet` you need an **instance** of `Pet` class. But in your code in the `Pet.name`, the `Pet` refers to the class and as there is no class variable `name` in `Pet` class, the above error is displayed.

To fix this, you can use the member `pets` of `Owner` class representing list of `Pet` object. So in the `get_pets_string()` you can iterate over `pets` member of `Owner` and print names of all the pets.

So after change to `get_pets_string()`, it will look like -

```
def get_pets_string(owner):
    result = owner.name.first + " " + owner.name.last + "'s pets are: "  + ", ".join(p.name.first + " " + p.name.last for p in owner.pets)
    return result
```

Here I have used `join()` to show the name of all the pets separated by comma